# Exclude rewrite directory form protectrion

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We have a magento installation. Because of dev purposes we have it closed with .htacces protection. But  I do want to open the API so I don't have to whitelist a bunch of 3rd party services.

The construction below does work for files that exist (`api.php`) but not for urls that are rewriten (`api`, `api/?wsdl`).

This `.htaccess` is one dir above the public_html. Based on [perishablepress](https://perishablepress.com/enable-file-or-directory-access-to-your-htaccess-password-protected-site/)

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Toegang nodig? neem gerust contact op: 038-8200270 !"
AuthUserFile /home/kijken/domains/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
Require valid-user
# allow public access to the following resources
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/api.php" allow
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/api/" allow  #api is not a real folder
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/api/?wsdl" allow

Order allow,deny
Allow from env=allow

Allow from 217.121.158.248 #Company HQ

Satisfy any
```

Magento with it's `.htaccess` is in the public_html, [mirror](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/.htaccess) of the file

What do I need to change to make it work with non existing files?
I don't mind a different setup as long as the following 3 criteria are met:

1. Whitelist IP (currently works)
2. Login for other IP's (currently works)
3. Exclude certain URL's (the root problem)

Comment: First of all, the grouping parenthesis in your regular expressions seem unnecessary (you are not using those captured values afterwards). Second of all, `Request_URI` does _not_ include the query string, as the documentation for `SetEnvIf` explicitly mentions. And with the line before that, you are anchoring your pattern at the string end; you should rather use a pattern that is anchored to the beginning.

Comment: Updated the expression. Any clue to help me with the problem itself?

Comment: I would assume that `^/api/` should work. Does `^/api.php` work as expected, when you request it without rewriting?

Comment: `^/api.php` works, `^/api/` does not work for `example.com/api/` nor for `example.com/api/?wsdl`

Comment: What i don't understand is why you put your htaccess one level up of `public_html` folder. It's never executed, considering that your document root folder is `public_html`. But let's say that's not the case here and your document root is `public_html`. You still have a problem because `api.php` is in `public_html` and that's not what `SetEnvIf` matches in your code (currently, it matches `/api.php` in root folder, not `/public_html/api.php`). So, you need to add some details in order to fully understand your problem

Comment: It's above the `public_html` because of git. Okay so to make it less complex. I've pasted it above the rest of the magento `.htacces` inside the `public_html`. Nothing changes about my question. The problems stay the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your setup and following your explanation, the easiest way of doing it would be to put your restriction code *at the top* of **Magento htaccess** (`/public_html/.htaccess`).

> I've pasted it above the rest of the magento .htacces inside the
>   public_html. Nothing changes about my question. The problems stay the
>   same.

That's because Magento's htaccess erases your restriction. You need to delete those 2 lines :

[image]

**Another detail**
`SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/api/?wsdl" allow` is useless since :

1. query string part (`wsdl` here) is not included in `Request_URI`
   (won't match what you expect)
2. previous rule (`SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/api/" allow`) is larger and includes your useless one

**Conclusion**
Here's how your final code should look like

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/api\.php$" allow
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/api/" allow

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Toegang nodig? neem gerust contact op: 038-8200270 !"
AuthUserFile /home/kijken/domains/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
Require valid-user
Order allow,deny
Allow from env=allow
Allow from 217.121.158.248
Satisfy any

# Magento htaccess code here
```

Tested and working

Comment: That works, *except* I also have to remove `RewriteRule .* index.php [L]` form the Magento rules. Kind of an important... Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Could you give me the case(s) when it's not working without removing that rule ?

Comment: How stupid of me not to clarify... `/api/` or `/api/?wdsl` doesn't work. `/api.php` does work. (not working meaning you still need to log in).

Comment: OK, I've just tested it by reproducing the (almost) same environment as yours and it seems i don't have the problem. At first, i thought it was because of the restriction after the rewrite to `index.php` but it's not. Right now, i don't know why it's not working on your side

Comment: Since it does work without the Magento part and does work for you I'll accept your answer. Our server is using directadmin I doubt anything is changed in the `httpd.conf`. Does this give you any idea's?

Comment: Well, i don't think it could be a problem, considering the cases when it does not work. I may have a temporary solution: try adding `SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/index\.php$" allow` and see how it behaves (you don't have to remove the `RewriteRule` in this case)

Comment: Oh and also... add `RewriteBase /` just after `RewriteEngine on` (without it, could be a problem for path resolving)

Comment: Yes that's it, It works. The `RewriteBase` doesn't appear necessary. Finally, I hate `.htaccess`

Comment: At first, it may seem mysterious but that's useful and fun actually. Glad it works and helped you

Answer (score 0):

To set an environment variable based on a CGI parameter you need to resort to mod_rewrite eg.

```
RewriteEngine On
# Set environment variable "allow" to Allow requests for /api/?wsdl
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING} wsdl
RewriteRule   ^/?api  - [E=allow:1]

# Set environment variable "allow" to Allow requests for URL's that are not Files (-f) and not Directories (-d)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ - [E=allow:1]
```

If you have access to the httpd.conf, stick the rules in the server config, as they only have to be parsed / compiled once, on server start-up, rather than for every request.

Comment: I guess I see the direction this is going, but since `.htaccess` is mostly black magic to me can you give a complete example in combination with my example?

Comment: Just have the RewriteRule directives appear before your: **Allow from env=allow**